# android Broadcast manager

Tags: android, eclipse

зачем в андроиде нужен объект broadcast receiver, если обработку action  из неявных интентов можно сделать в сервис либо на активности ?

Comment: Прочитайте вот это http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/broadcast.php

Comment: я прочитал там написано только  о том что можно создавать Receiver посредством манифеста либо программным путем

Comment: Broadcast среагирует на событие и в том случае, если активити или сервис не запущены и уже через него стартует активити/сервис

Answer (score 1):

**Сервисы**: стоит использовать, если вы хотите, чтобы что-то работало в фоновом режиме, даже в случае, если приложение закрыто. Вы можете создать сервис в отдельном процессе, а также, если хотите, вы можете передать ваш сервис в другое приложение. Загрузка любого содержимого или воспроизведение музыки является хорошим примером.

**Широковещательные сообщения**: используются, когда вы хотите выполнить какое-нибудь действие во время какого-либо события. Например, при загрузке устройства: если вы хотите выполнить что-то, когда устройство загружается, к примеру, изменить дату и время, подойдёт `Broadcast manager`.

**!** Также отличие их заключается в том, что сервисы могут выполнять длительную (условно неограниченную во времени) фоновую задачу, а приёмники широковещательных сообщений работают в течение короткого промежутка времени, только чтобы обработать событие.